# What is the running time for size on Scala's ListBuffer?

Tags: scala

Is it constant or O(n)? If O(n) are there similar data structures with constant time size operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely, `size` and `length` have different descriptions in the [ListBuffer docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer). For sure, `ListBuffer.length` is constant time. Prior to Scala 2.8, `length` was indeed O(n), but this is [now fixed](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Alternative-to-ListBuffer-with-constant-time-length-tp1946599p1946601.html). The [implementation of `size`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_0_1/src//library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L1) in `TraversableOnce` suggests that it is O(n), but I may be missing something.

Other performance characteristics of Scala collections are [documented here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html). For `ListBuffer` specifically,

```
             head     tail     apply   update   prepend  append  insert
 ListBuffer  C        L        L       L        C        C       L
```

where C is constant and L is linear time.

Edit : Both ListBuffer length and size are now O(1) - The issue mentioned by @KiptonBarros was closed with Scala 2.9.1 see: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4933

Comment: Both `length` and `size` are linear on `TraversableOnce`. Indeed, `size` on `ListBuffer` is linear, because it is forwarded to `underlying`, which is `List` on `ListBuffer`. That is worth a ticket.

Comment: Funny that `append` is constant and `tail` remains linear.

Comment: `tail` produces a new collection, `append` mutates the existing one.